Fetch method delete react
I need help when clicking on my icon the corresponding message deletes it
I can't get my route to work on the front side
mon code front
const handleTrash = (id) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/deleteTweet/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      // headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      // body: JSON.stringify({ id: tweet._id }),
    }).then((response => response.json()) => {
      console.log(response.status);
    });
    // .then((response) => response.json())
    // .then((data) => {
    //   console.log("data is", data);
    // })
    // .then((response) => response.json())
    // .then((data) => {
    //   setTrash(!trash);
    //   console.log("Delete :", reponse);
    // });
  };

ma route back
router.delete("/deleteTweet/:id", (req, res) => {
  // if (!checkUser(req.params.token)) {
  //   res.json({ results: false, error: "Missing or empty fields" });
  //   return;
  // }
  Tweet.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(() =>
    res.json({ result: true })
  );
});


Does the Tweet.deleteOne function return anything ?

Please add more information to this question. Also, the text "mon code front" does not make any sense to me. Including some figures will be helpful too!
